# How to input the "OAuth Developer Verification Form" when the Client is Salesface?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Recently I received a mail from
google that said I need to submitting the "OAuth Developer Verification
Form" because "Your Google Cloud/APIs project XXXXX has not completed this process and has reached 60% of this
user limit".

So for submitting this form, I have some questions.

1. Because we invoke the DialogFlow API from a cloud platform(SalesForce)
   which is used in internal and we have not the user registration process. So
   we have not "Application Privacy Policy link", how we input "Application Privacy Policy link" in "OAuth
   Developer Verification Form" ?
2. Event we input "Application Homepage link" in "OAuth Developer
   Verification Form",  it will be redirected to the login page for user can
   not register user by yourself. Is that OK ?

Comment: Who is the user of your application? If the project is used internally within your organization, you may not need to request verification.

Comment: We use this application internally, But I don't think the Google can know that. Can I ignore the email from Google ?

Comment: To use the app internally, you'll have to associate it with your GSuite account. That's how Google knows. I think that if you ignore this email, your OAuth app will get disabled when you reach the 100 user limit. Here's Google's description of the limits and the possible results: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865.